# nginx shows ip of docker network instead of user ip

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

Having trouble using Nginx with Docker. When I don't use Nginx I see the users correct `10.xxx.xx.xx` IP, but when I use Nginx to proxy, my application shows a `192` address from the docker container network. None of the existing answers I have read have been able to help.

My Nginx settings are as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location ~* ^/websiteName/ {
        real_ip_recursive on;
        # Strip the prefix and then proxy pass
        rewrite ^/websiteName/(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://imt_webapp:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Header-Test "X-Forwarded-For - $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";
        proxy_set_header X-Header-Test "X-Real-IP - $remote_addr";
    }
}
```

The above show these IP addresses:

```
X-Real-Ip: 192.168.144.1
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.144.1
```

They appear to be the addresses of the docker network:

```
docker ps -q | xargs -n 1 docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} 0 {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'
/{{container-name}}-nginx-1 0 192.168.144.3
/{{container-name}}-imt_webapp-1 0 192.168.144.2
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
    imt_webapp:
        build: ./src/
        volumes: 
            - ./src/:/usr/src/app/
        ports: 
            - ${FLASK_PORT}:5000
        environment: 
            PORT: 5000
            FLASK_DEBUG: 1
        networks:
            - mynet

    imt_database:
        image: mysql:8.0
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
        ports:
           - "${DATABASE_PORT}:3306"
        volumes:
            - imt-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - mynet
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:            
          - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d   
        networks:
            - mynet
volumes:
  imt-mysql-data:

networks:
  mynet:
    external: False
```

Comment: You need to place your deployment behind the standalone proxy. While deployed in the Docker it has no network information

Comment: so you mean to start an nginx container separately and give it host network settings?